# Connected Planar Graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In a connected planar graph, every vertex has degree $3$, and every face is bordered by $5$ or $6$ edges. How many faces are bordered by $5$ edges?

Answer (score 2):

Let $n, e, f, x$ represent the number of vertices, the number of edges, the number of faces, and the number of faces bordered by $5$ edges, respectively. By the handshaking lemma, we have:
$$
2e = \sum_{v \in V} \deg v = 3n
$$
Likewise, by applying the handshaking lemma to the dual graph $G^*$, we have:
$$
2e = \sum_{i} |F_i| = 5x + 6(f - x) = 6f - x \iff 6f = 2e + x
$$
We can use these two equations with Euler's Formula to solve for $x$:
\begin{align*}
n - e + f &= 2 \\
2(3n) - 6e + (6f) &= 12 \\
2(2e) - 6e + (2e + x) &= 12 \\
x &= 12
\end{align*}